# How does Yacc expand this rule?

Tags: c, linked-list, lex

I have the following rule in `Yacc` out of which I want to make a linked list, however I keep getting the last node in the list when I try to print it:

```
node_list
:                                                   {$$=NULL;}
| node_list node                                    {if ($1 != NULL) $1->next=$2; $$=$2;    }
;
```

My understanding is if for example this is the list

```
node1
node2
node3
```

`Yacc` would expand this as

```
node_list node3
node_list node2 node3
ndoe_list node1 node2 node3
NULL node1 node2 node3
```

but since I am getting the last node with the above code then my guess is that the list is expanded in revere order

```
node_list node1
node_list node2 node1
ndoe_list node3 node2 node1
NULL node3 node2 node1
```

so then I try with this code:

```
node_list
:                                                   {$$=NULL;}
| node_list node                                    {$2->next=$1; $$=$2 ;   }
;
```

I understand that in each case I am returning the last node in the list and that is why I am getting only one node. So then I tried this code:

```
node_list
:                                                   {$$=NULL;}
| node_list node                                    {$$=linkXmlNode($1,$2);}
;
```

where `linkXmlNode` is

```
XmlNode * linkXmlNode(XmlNode * first, XmlNode * second)
{
XmlNode * temp = second;
while (second->next != NULL) 
    second=second->next;

second->next=first; 
return temp;
}
```

Now I am getting the last node repeated 3 times each time. I tried the other direction too, but now I get the first node:

```
XmlNode * linkXmlNode(XmlNode * first, XmlNode * second)
{
if (first == NULL) return second;
XmlNode * temp = first;
while (first->next != NULL)
    first= first->next;
first->next = second;
return temp
}
```

If someone knows how exactly `Yacc` expands the list that would be great.

---

**EDIT: ANSWER**
I had a mistake in my print function, the functions above work. The error was that instead of printing the iterator I was printing the parameter, thus getting the same node multiple times.

Comment: This looks more like `yacc` than `lex` to me.

Comment: Have you tried to print `$1` and `$2`?

Comment: @n.m. I had a mistake in my print function, the functions above work. The error was that instead of printing the iterator I was printing the parameter, thus getting the same node multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the following productions:

```
 => nodeList
nodeList node1 => nodeList
nodeList node2 => nodeList
nodeList node3 => nodeList
```

So in your first case your list starts off at null, then it has node1 prepended to it, then it has node2 prepended to it, then it has node3 prepended to it. I was going to say that your code to link the node to the end of the list should result in your final list in ascending order, but I've just seen your edit suggesting that it was correct all along.

Comment: Yes, the last function was correct. Regarding your answer, so the parsing it goes in a Top-Down order?

Comment: @mihajlv yacc is a LALR parser generator, which is a type of bottom-up parser, although your grammar can probably be parsed using an LL top-down parser.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($1 != NULL) $1->next=$2; $$=$2;
```

returns `$2`, but `$2` is not pointing to `$1`; you pointed `$1` to `$2` instead, but you don't return `$1` so nothing will ever know about it.  (How is something, given only `$2`, supposed to know how to get to `$1` given that it's only `$1` that knows about the relationship?)

```
$2->next=$1; $$=$2
```

should get you your list, but in reverse order.  To get it in the other order, you need to either pass both a head and tail pointer, or insert an additional rule over the list to invert the list before passing it on.

Your third attempt is closest to correct in terms of linking; it leaves the question of how you are copying list elements around, if you are getting the same data.  Note that `yacc` itself knows nothing about your list; *it* does not "expand" the list at all, that is what *your* code is supposed to do.

(It is not clear to me if your latest comment indicates that you have resolved your question.)

Comment: The latest function works, I had a mistake in the print function, it was printing the same node multiple times since I was printing the parameter not the iterator that iterates the list. Thanks for the explanation though, that makes sense.